# Not search the part that was previously searched Officejs

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-web-addins

"I have something with me."
Currently I am using
`context.document.body.search('something', { matchCase: true, matchWholeWord: true }).load('items/NoPropertiesNeeded');`
to search 'something' and the 'something' gets loaded in the taskpane.

"I have something with me. something is bothering me"
Now I dont want to search the 'something' on first paragraph that was already searched and loaded in taskpane.
How can I do so?

Answer (score 0):

The [Word.SearchOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.searchoptions?view=word-js-preview) class doesn't provide anything for that. You need to iterate over search results like shown below and excluded unwanted results from the view or just skip them:

```
// Run a batch operation against the Word object model.
await Word.run(async (context) => {

    // Queue a command to search the document and ignore punctuation.
    const searchResults = context.document.body.search('video you', {ignorePunct: true});

    // Queue a command to load the font property values.
    searchResults.load('font');

    // Synchronize the document state.
    await context.sync();
    console.log('Found count: ' + searchResults.items.length);

    // Queue a set of commands to change the font for each found item.
    for (let i = 0; i < searchResults.items.length; i++) {
        searchResults.items[i].font.color = 'purple';
        searchResults.items[i].font.highlightColor = '#FFFF00'; //Yellow
        searchResults.items[i].font.bold = true;
    }

    // Synchronize the document state.
    await context.sync();
});
```

See [Use search options in your Word add-in to find text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/word/search-option-guidance) for more information.

Note, you can post or vote for an existing feature request on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) where they are considered when the Office dev team goes through the planning process.